# On source of heat energy dissipation in a system

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, friction, work

Suppose we have a block of mass m which was at rest on a rough floor and is now given an impulse towards a wall.It is given that the collision with wall is perfectly elastic and no energy is lost in it.It is given that block comes to rest at its starting position after the collision.Friction does no work on the block as displacement is 0.But there would be inevitably heat loss on account of friction interacting with the blocks bottom surface's particles.My question is where is the this energy of heat loss coming from as the friction doesn't do any work on the system and there wouldn't be any change in the mechanical energy of the system.Whose work is accounting for the heat loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Friction does no work on the block as displacement is 0.

That is incorrect.

Friction is not a conservative force, like gravity. The work done by gravity depends only on the end points and not on the path traveled. The work done by friction is  along the entire path  of travel and therefore depends on the length $L$ of the path.

So the work done by friction in your example would equal

$$W=FL=μ_{k}mgL$$

Where $F$ is the kinetic friction force, $μ_{k}$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction, and $L$ is the total distance traveled by your block of  mass $m$ from the starting point back to its starting point.

All of the work done by friction is dissipated as heat.

Hope this  helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly friction is a non conservative force, so  it s path dependent, so the total work done is not zero, one more thing I want to add is here direction of friction is different in both the direction.